# Using different TypeVar for subclass of a Generic class

Tags: python, pycharm, type-hinting, python-typing

Pycharm gives an `Expected type X, got X instead` type warning on the last line. The issue goes away if I use the same TypeVar for both the superclass and the subclass, but considering these classes will be in different files and the subclass will use a `bound` TypeVar, that is not possible.

I'm I missing something? Or should I report it as a bug? This is with python 3.7 on Pycharm 2019.2.6.

```
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

U = TypeVar("U")


class A(Generic[U]):
    def __init__(self, model: U):
        pass

    def func(self, b: U) -> U:
        return b


T = TypeVar("T")


class B(A[T]):
    def __init__(self, model: T):
        super().__init__(model)


B("").func("")  #Expected type 'str' (matched generic type 'U'), got 'str' instead
```

Comment: I agree that this seems like a bug. FWIW, mypy type checks this without complaining: https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.8&gist=a00deb7e99d528eeea62fa53c81a22ad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted an [issue on the Pycharm issue tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-41801), the bug is fixed in version 2020.1